# cell data to proper table conversion in matlab2009

Tags: database, matlab

I am using matlab 2009 version. I am acessing data through database using [following code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593485/how-to-connect-to-microsoft-sql-server-2008-mssql-from-matlab)

```
    conn = actxserver('ADODB.Connection');
    conn.Open('Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=user_control_ex01;Integrated Security=SSPI;');
    dat=conn.Execute('select * from user_ident').GetRows;
```

the table returned is in this format

```
dat = 

[         1]    [         2]    [         3]    [         4]
'Admin     '    'user      '    'user2     '    'hello     '
'Admin     '    'user      '    'user2     '    'hello123  '
```

As you can see this is 2x4 cell returned object. I want this cell to be converted into proper table or some format where I can access the exact row column entry. I am thinking to use this cell as it is but could not getting idea how to proceed. I want to access data with row_number and column number reference. Could someone please provide some help as this cell is not int proper row column format it is presenting one row as column.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like you've got a 3x4 cell with the column header (numeric in this case) stuffed in the first row. If that's the case, you could just strip off the header.

```
datHeader = dat(1,:);
datRows = dat(2:end,:);
```

Then you can index into it with `datRows{iRow}{iColumn}`.

However, if you're working with larger data sets and have any numeric data, you'll probably want to convert the numeric columns from `cell` arrays to `double` arrays, and store your data as a cell array of column vectors instead of a 2-D cell array. And call `deblank()` on the char columns to trim off the trailing whitespace, which is appropriate for a 2-D `char` array but not for `cellstr`s.